CopyClipboard in Wix installer
Using System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText() in Wix installer Custom Action is throwing the following error

DEBUG: Error 2896:  Executing action CopyToClipBoard failed.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2896. The arguments are: CopyToClipBoard

The same code in a regular desktop app works fine.
The CustomAction is defined as follows:
<CustomAction Id="CopyToClipBoard" BinaryKey="CheckRegistryEntry" DllEntry="CopyToClipBoard" Execute="immediate" />

I tried different execute options like "deferred" but no success.
CustomAction is defined as follows:
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult CopyToClipBoard(Session xiSession)
{
    xiSession["DEBUGMESSAGE"] = "Fetching Installation ID ";
    var instID = GetPhysicalID(xiSession);
    xiSession["DEBUGMESSAGE"] = "Installation ID - " + instID;
    Clipboard.SetText(instID);
    return ActionResult.Success;
}

GetPhysicalID method executed successfully but when it executes Clipboard.SetText, the installer ends with the error as shown above.
Thanks in advance
Subhash

Any comments/pointers from this esteemed group? - thanks
